# SharedPreferences between different apps works on emulator, not on device

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, emulation

I'm trying to save some keys with SharedPreferences on the first APP, then when initialized the second APP, load them.
It works on the emulator but not on a device (Android 4.0.3)

This is my code on the first APP:

```
private SharedPreferences gameSaved;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

gameSaved = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
int value = 10;
editor = gameSaved.edit();
editor.putInt("value_0", value);
editor.commit();
```

Then on the second APP I get the key value like this:

```
try{
   con = getApplicationContext().createPackageContext("com.example.firstapp", 0);
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
}
SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
int value = pref.getInt("value_0", -1);
```

On the manifest both APPs share this line:

```
android:sharedUserId="com.example.shared"
```

I've check that SharedPreferences file is correctly created and located.
The most strange thing is it works perfectly on the emulator.
Please help, I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Did you make sure both apps are signed with the same certificate?

Comment: How can I check which certificate each APP has?

Comment: If you installed both apps from the same IDE on the same PC, they should be signed with the same debug certificate, if you don't have another certificate specified.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the same IDE on the same PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally could solve it but I don't have any technical explanation for it.

Previously I had on both APPs the same file name for it:

```
SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(FILE_NAME, Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
```

It doesn't have much sense because those files are stored/saved in the different APP's data folder but if they share the same SharedPreferences file name then it won't work (at least for me).